# wso2 ei 660. Critical BUG when use script mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I used code in resource

```
<resource faultSequence="fault_simple" methods="GET" protocol="https" uri-template="/all">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="REQUEST_TIMESTAMP" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="get_balancing"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var requestTimeStamp = mc.getProperty("REQUEST_TIMESTAMP");  
                      var responseTimeStamp = mc.getProperty("RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP");  
                      var responseTime = (responseTimeStamp - requestTimeStamp)/1000;  
                      mc.setProperty("RESPONSE_TIME", responseTime);]]>
            </script>
            <log>
                    <property expression="$ctx:RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP" name="RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP"/>
                    <property expression="$ctx:REQUEST_TIMESTAMP" name="REQUEST_TIMESTAMP"/>
                    <property expression="$ctx:RESPONSE_TIME" name="RESPONSE_TIME"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
```

When send in endpoint working < 1 second, this works as well, But if send working more than 8-9 seconds I have a mistake

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:613d12e7-d692-4ac7-8a20-6b798f811edb, Direction: response, RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP = 1592573342279, REQUEST_TIMESTAMP = 1592573333377
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} - The script engine returned an Exception executing the external js script : null function mediate java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: out of range index
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:613d12e7-d692-4ac7-8a20-6b798f811edb, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = The script engine returned an Exception executing the external js script : null function mediate
```

When i remove mediator script from code, sevice working as well (send working more than 8-9 sec)

p.s. I tried use JS/Groovy/Python - result is the same.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I think its worth to try. I've had some weird behaviour when I used inline scripts. After moving the scripts to the registry everything works fine on my side. You'll find more information here calling scripts from registry.     https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Script+Mediator#ScriptMediator-Example2-Usingascriptsavedintheregistry

Comment: thank's. But this is doesn't working too. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs due to the script mediator trying to read a large array of the response (always).

The solution is as follows:

```
<resource faultSequence="fault_simple" methods="GET" protocol="https" uri-template="/all">
    <inSequence>
        <property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="REQUEST_TIMESTAMP" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="get_balancing"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
        <property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="RESPONSE_TIME" scope="default" expression="$ctx:RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP - $ctx:REQUEST_TIMESTAMP"/>
        <log>
                <property expression="$ctx:RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP" name="RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:REQUEST_TIMESTAMP" name="REQUEST_TIMESTAMP"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:RESPONSE_TIME" name="RESPONSE_TIME"/>
        </log>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
</resource>
```

instead  JS script - this

```
<property name="RESPONSE_TIME" scope="default" expression="$ctx:RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP - $ctx:REQUEST_TIMESTAMP"/>
```